# How to set InfoPath form fields values in task list without using workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath, caml-query, forms-services

I have 5x action items fields on the InfoPath form. This form have more than 500 fields so get touching the boundary limits in terms text box fields datatype. Is there any way that we can set the form's fields values in task list on form submit without workflow?
Can we do this using InfoPath rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a field's value on form submit, you can add a button and set rules on the button as the following:
[image]